# Curl library in cpuminer Android

Tags: android, c, curl, android-ndk, libcurl

I followed this tutorial: https://github.com/mdelling/cpuminer-android from github, but it gives me a Force Close error when I load the app into my Nexus 5 KitKat 4.4.2

I compiled the library using the lastest Android NDK (r10b), but I don't know how to move the compiled library into the project (or more specifically, what files from the compiled folder libcurl do I need to add into my project?).

Here is the logcat error:

```
    10-14 19:49:54.867: E/AndroidRuntime(30231): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-14 19:49:54.867: E/AndroidRuntime(30231): Process: com.mdelling.cpuminer, PID: 30231
10-14 19:49:54.867: E/AndroidRuntime(30231): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load curl from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mdelling.cpuminer-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.mdelling.cpuminer-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
10-14 19:49:54.867: E/AndroidRuntime(30231):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
10-14 19:49:54.867: E/AndroidRuntime(30231):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
10-14 19:49:54.867: E/AndroidRuntime(30231):    at com.mdelling.cpuminer.CPUMinerApplication.<clinit>(CPUMinerApplication.java:38)
10-14 19:49:54.867: E/AndroidRuntime(30231):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-14 19:49:54.867: E/AndroidRuntime(30231):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
10-14 19:49:54.867: E/AndroidRuntime(30231):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:990)
10-14 19:49:54.867: E/AndroidRuntime(30231):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:975)
10-14 19:49:54.867: E/AndroidRuntime(30231):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:502)
10-14 19:49:54.867: E/AndroidRuntime(30231):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4301)
10-14 19:49:54.867: E/AndroidRuntime(30231):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-14 19:49:54.867: E/AndroidRuntime(30231):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-14 19:49:54.867: E/AndroidRuntime(30231):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-14 19:49:54.867: E/AndroidRuntime(30231):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-14 19:49:54.867: E/AndroidRuntime(30231):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
10-14 19:49:54.867: E/AndroidRuntime(30231):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-14 19:49:54.867: E/AndroidRuntime(30231):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-14 19:49:54.867: E/AndroidRuntime(30231):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
10-14 19:49:54.867: E/AndroidRuntime(30231):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
10-14 19:49:54.867: E/AndroidRuntime(30231):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the error caused by us not running things from the right directory.
If you follow the tutorial exactly, there will be no issues.

It is very important that you use the NDK version specified in the tutorial, not a newer one.

Answer (score 0):

directory you are looking for:
Ant: /libs/
gradle: /main/libs

under libs/ their will be arch specific directories.
example: libs/armeabi <--- copy library compiled for ARM here